# Vertical line in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Any idea why I am getting multiple lines on other columns in  ggplot when I m trying to plot only one vertical line on col4 in ggplot?

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

Col0 <- c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD","EE","FF")
Col1 <- c(2,2,2,6,1,1)
Col2 <- c(2,2,2,1,3,4)
Col3 <- c(2,2,3,4,6,6)
Col4 <- c(2,2,3,1,2,1)
Col5 <- c(2,1,1,1,1,4)
Col6 <- c(2,4,2,5,4,4)
Col7 <- c(2,4,2,5,4,4)
Col8 <- c(2,2,3,4,5,4)
Col9 <- c(1,3,3,2,2,2)
df<-data.frame(Col0,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9)


plotDat <- df %>%
  gather(Col, Val, -Col0)%>%
  split(Col0)

pdf("plots.pdf")
lapply(names(plotDat), function(i){
  ggplot(plotDat[[i]], aes(Col, Val, group = Col0, col = Col0)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_vline(xintercept = Col4) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = Col4, linetype="dotted", color = "blue", size=1.5)+
    ggtitle(paste("Plot", i))
  })
dev.off()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display a vline on the 4th break on the (discrete) x-axis, set `xintercept = 4`

So, replace `Col4` with `4` in both `geom_vline`-lines

```
pdf("plots.pdf")
lapply(names(plotDat), function(i){
  ggplot(plotDat[[i]], aes(Col, Val, group = Col0, col = Col0)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_vline(xintercept = 4) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = 4, linetype="dotted", color = "blue", size=1.5)+
    ggtitle(paste("Plot", i))
})
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Is there anyway to pass column name(x axis) for intercept?

Comment: @SamsungNeo, probably.., make it a factor, and try to refer to the correct level